# Is it possible to pass data from one directive to another?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have created two directive. One is handling events for Modal Popup and another is handling custom tool tip events. Now all I need to do is pass data from Modal directive to tool tip directive. I have tried google it but didn't got anything useful. So is there really any way through which we can pass the value from one directive to another?

Tooltip Directive is as follows :

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input, HostListener, Renderer, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ReportModel } from '../../models/ReportModel';
//import {FormFieldModel } from '../../models/FormFieldModel';
import { FormFieldModel } from '../../models/FrameworkElementFormFieldModel';

 @Directive( 
 {
    selector: '[Tooltip]'
 }
)

export class TooltipDirective {

constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer) { }
tooltipTitle: any = '';
tooltipText: any = '';
tooltipImage: any = '';
isFormFieldModel: boolean = false;
@Input() dataContext: any = new ReportModel();
@Input() IsButtonPanel: boolean = false;



private mouseTop: number = 0;
private mouseLeft: number = 0;
tooltipTop: number = 0;
tooltipLeft: number = 0;
@HostListener('click') onclick() {
    this.hover(false);
}

@HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) onMouseEnter(event: MouseEvent) {debugger
    this.hover(false);
    if (this.mainDiv != null) {
        this.mainDiv.remove();
        this.ImgElement.remove();
    }
    this.mouseLeft = event.clientX;
    this.mouseTop = event.clientY;
    if (this.dataContext != null) {

        this.tooltipText = this.dataContext.Description;

        if (this.dataContext instanceof FormFieldModel) {
            this.isFormFieldModel = true;
        }

        if (this.isFormFieldModel) {
            if (!this.dataContext.IsShowToolTip) {
                return;
            }
            this.tooltipTitle = this.dataContext.PrettyName;
        }
        else {
            this.tooltipTitle = this.dataContext.Header;
            this.tooltipImage = this.dataContext.Icon;
        }

        if (this.tooltipTitle == '' || this.tooltipTitle == null || this.tooltipTitle == 'null') {
            this.tooltipTitle = "Header";
        }

        if (this.tooltipText == null || this.tooltipText == 'null') {
            this.tooltipText = "";
        }

        if (this.tooltipImage == '' || this.tooltipImage == 'null') {
            this.tooltipImage = "info.png";
        }

        this.hover(true);
    }
}
@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.hover(false);
}

@HostListener('focusin') onFocus() {

    if (this.mainDiv != null) {
        this.mainDiv.remove();
        this.ImgElement.remove();
    }

    this.mouseLeft = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    this.mouseTop = this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    if (this.dataContext != null) {

        this.tooltipText = this.dataContext.Description;

        if (this.dataContext instanceof FormFieldModel) {
            this.isFormFieldModel = true;
        }

        if (this.isFormFieldModel) {
            if (!this.dataContext.IsShowToolTip) {
                return;
            }
            this.tooltipTitle = this.dataContext.PrettyName;
        }
        else {
            this.tooltipTitle = this.dataContext.Header;
            this.tooltipImage = this.dataContext.Icon;
        }

        if (this.tooltipTitle == '' || this.tooltipTitle == null || this.tooltipTitle == 'null') {
            this.tooltipTitle = "Header";
        }

        if (this.tooltipText == null || this.tooltipText == 'null') {
            this.tooltipText = "";
        }

        if (this.tooltipImage == '' || this.tooltipImage == 'null') {
            this.tooltipImage = "info.png";
        }

        this.hover(true);
    }
}

@HostListener('focusout') onFocusout(target) {
    this.hover(false);
}

//@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
//onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
//    this.mouseLeft = event.clientX;
//    this.mouseTop = event.clientY;
//}

mainDiv: any; ImgElement: any; InputElement: any; divElement: any; divElement1: any; divElement2: any;
hover(onMouseHover: boolean) {debugger

    if (onMouseHover && !this.IsButtonPanel) {debugger
        //Dynamically Create Img Element   

        //Delete existing Tooltip
        let tooltipItem = this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName("tooltipMain")[0];
        if (tooltipItem != null) {
            tooltipItem.outerHTML = '';
        }
        else
        {
            tooltipItem = this.el.nativeElement.nextElementSibling;
            if (tooltipItem != null && tooltipItem.className.indexOf("tooltipMain") >= 0)
            {
                tooltipItem.outerHTML = '';
            }
        }

        this.ImgElement = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, "img");

        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.ImgElement, "src", "images/" + this.tooltipImage);

        //if (this.tooltipImage == '') {
        //    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.ImgElement, "src", "images/info.png");
        //}
        //else {
        //    this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.ImgElement, "src", "images/" + this.tooltipImage);
        //}

        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "width", "40px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "height", "40px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "margin-right", "2px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "float", "left");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "border", "1px solid #CCC");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "border-radius", "5px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "padding", "5px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.ImgElement, "backgroundColor", "#f5f5f5");

        //tooltip text outer div

        this.divElement = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, "div");

        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "border", "1px solid #CCC");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "margin-left", "38px !important");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "color", "black");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "border-radius", "5px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "padding", "5px");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "float", "left");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "backgroundColor", "#f5f5f5");
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.divElement, "text-align", "left !important");

        //tooltip text header div

        this.divElement1 = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, "div");

        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.divElement1, "header", true);
        this.renderer.createText(this.divElement1, this.tooltipTitle);


        //tooltip text description div

        this.divElement2 = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, "div");

        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.divElement2, "description", true);
        this.renderer.createText(this.divElement2, this.tooltipText);


        this.mainDiv = this.renderer.createElement(this.el.nativeElement, "div");

        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.mainDiv, "disabled", true);
        this.renderer.setElementClass(this.mainDiv, "tooltipMain", true);


        let tooltipWidth = this.mainDiv.clientWidth + 10;
        let tooltipHeight = this.mainDiv.clientHeight + 10;

        let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
        let windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

        if ((windowWidth - this.mouseLeft) < tooltipWidth) {
            //this.tooltipLeft = windowWidth - (tooltipWidth);
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainDiv, "right", "0px");
        } else {
            //this.tooltipLeft = this.mouseLeft;
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainDiv, "left", this.mouseLeft + "px");
        }

        if ((windowHeight - this.mouseTop) < tooltipHeight) {
            this.tooltipTop = this.mouseTop - 20;
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainDiv, "bottom", "0px");
        } else {
            this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainDiv, "top", this.mouseTop  + 5 + "px");
        }

        this.mainDiv.appendChild(this.ImgElement);
        this.divElement.appendChild(this.divElement1);
        this.divElement.appendChild(this.divElement2);
        this.mainDiv.appendChild(this.divElement);
        //this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainDiv, "left", this.tooltipLeft + "px");
        //this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.mainDiv, "top", this.tooltipTop + "px");  
    }
    else {
        if (this.mainDiv != null) {
            this.mainDiv.remove();
            this.ImgElement.remove();
        }
    }
}
}
```

And my Popup Draggable Directive is as follows :

```js
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

 @Directive({
   selector: '[draggable-component]'
 })
export class DraggableDirective implements OnInit {
topStart: number = 0;
leftStart: number = 0;
_allowDrag: boolean = true;
valueTop: any = 0;
valueLeft: any = 0;
md: boolean;

constructor(public element: ElementRef) { }

ngOnInit() {
    if (this._allowDrag) {
        this.element.nativeElement.style.position = 'absolute';
    }
}

@HostListener('mousedown', ['$event'])
onMouseDown(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (event.button === 2)
        return; // prevents right click drag, remove his if you don't want it
    this.md = true;
    this.topStart = event.clientY - this.element.nativeElement.style.top.replace('px', '');
    this.leftStart = event.clientX - this.element.nativeElement.style.left.replace('px', '');
}

@HostListener('document:mouseup')
onMouseUp(event: MouseEvent) {
    this.md = false;
}

@HostListener('document:mousemove', ['$event'])
onMouseMove(event: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.md && this._allowDrag) {

        this.valueTop = this.element.nativeElement.style.top = (event.clientY - this.topStart) + 'px';
        console.log(this.valueTop);
        this.valueLeft = this.element.nativeElement.style.left = (event.clientX - this.leftStart) + 'px';
        console.log(this.valueLeft);
    }
}

@HostListener('touchstart', ['$event'])
onTouchStart(event: TouchEvent) {
    this.md = true;
    this.topStart = event.changedTouches[0].clientY - this.element.nativeElement.style.top.replace('px', '');
    this.leftStart = event.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.element.nativeElement.style.left.replace('px', '');
    event.stopPropagation();
}

@HostListener('document:touchend')
onTouchEnd() {
    this.md = false;
}

@HostListener('document:touchmove', ['$event'])
onTouchMove(event: TouchEvent) {
    if (this.md && this._allowDrag) {
        this.element.nativeElement.style.top = (event.changedTouches[0].clientY - this.topStart) + 'px';
        this.element.nativeElement.style.left = (event.changedTouches[0].clientX - this.leftStart) + 'px';
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
}
}
```

Now i need to pass `valueTop` and `valueLeft` from Draggable directive to Tooltip. And this is what I want.

Comment: Please post some code. What elements are the directives added to?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hi, My directives looking for the events like Dragging the model and Mouse and touch enter and move. So i just want to pass value from one directive to another. I just want to know whether it is possible or not. And if it is possible then how. I am just looking for the Demo.

Comment: It's possible, and how depends where you directives are, therefore please show some code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Check I have updated the code. These two directives are used dynamically in the application

Comment: is there any parent/child relationship between your directives ? Are-they siblings, not related at all ?

Comment: No they are not related at all. Both are independent. @n00dl3

Answer (score 2):

As your directives are not related, you will need to create a service that will be injected in both your directives, that service will be the communication channel between them :

```js
@Injectable()
export class Myservice{
  private _foo=new BehaviorSubject<string>("foo");
  setFoo(foo:string){
    this._foo.next(foo);
  }
  foo = this._foo.asObservable()
}
```

```js
@Directive({
   selector: '[draggable-component]'
 })
export class DraggableDirective{
  constructor(public element: ElementRef, private service: MyService) {
    this.service.setFoo("bar");
  }
}
```

```js
@Directive( 
{
  selector: '[Tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective {

  constructor(public el: ElementRef, public renderer: Renderer, private service:MyService) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.service.foo.subscribe(value=>console.log(value));
  }

}
```

Note that I use a `BehaviorSubject` because you might be confronted to `DraggableDirective` emitting a value before the other one has subscribed to it, so not getting the right value at the right time. But you are totally free for the implementation, you can even use a pattern that is not based on `Observable`/`Subject` if you think it would better fit your needs.

Comment: Is there any other way in which i dont need to use this service?

Comment: If directives are unrelated, that's the only way. If they were parent/child you could use `@Input()` and `@Output()`, or inject parent into child if there was a "transclusion" : `<parent><child></child></parent>`